# Tensorflow: Not found: Key test/global_step not found in checkpoint

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I got these errors below when i restore my trained model. What would cause this situation happened and how to figure out these errors? Appreciate it!!!

```
    2017-08-10 09:50:09.228153: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1158] Not found: Key test/Q_forward/RNN/rnn/gru_cell/candidate/bias not found in checkpoint

2017-08-10 09:50:09.228153: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1158] Not found: Key test/P_forward/RNN/rnn/gru_cell/gates/kernel not found in checkpoint

2017-08-10 09:50:09.228184: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1158] Not found: Key test/global_step not found in checkpoint

2017-08-10 09:50:09.228231: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1158] Not found: Key test/P_forward/RNN/rnn/gru_cell/candidate/kernel not found in checkpoint

2017-08-10 09:50:09.228260: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1158] Not found: Key test/P_forward/embs/embs not found in checkpoint

2017-08-10 09:50:09.228353: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1158] Not found: Key test/P_forward/RNN/rnn/gru_cell/candidate/bias not found in checkpoint

2017-08-10 09:50:09.228558: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1158] Not found: Key test/P_forward/RNN/rnn/gru_cell/gates/bias not found in checkpoint

2017-08-10 09:50:09.229262: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1158] Not found: Key test/Q_forward/RNN/rnn/gru_cell/candidate/kernel not found in checkpoint

2017-08-10 09:50:09.229581: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1158] Not found: Key test/Q_forward/RNN/rnn/gru_cell/gates/kernel not found in checkpoint

2017-08-10 09:50:09.229610: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1158] Not found: Key test/Q_forward/embs/embs not found in checkpoint

2017-08-10 09:50:09.229646: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1158] Not found: Key test/Q_forward/RNN/rnn/gru_cell/gates/bias not found in checkpoint
```

And this is Traceback:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ljn/PycharmProjects/RNN_QA/src/QA_lstm.py", line 529, in <module>tf.app.run()

 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 48, in run
    _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))

File "/home/ljn/PycharmProjects/RNN_QA/src/QA_lstm.py", line 515, in main
    Test(train_model, te_data_batches, config, FLAGS.num_steps_pre, 
FLAGS.num_steps_q, triplet, vocab)

 File "/home/ljn/PycharmProjects/RNN_QA/src/QA_lstm.py", line 400, in Test
    model.saver.restore(sess, ckpt_state.model_checkpoint_path) #tf.train.latest_checkpoint('../data/log_root/.')

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1548, in restore
    {self.saver_def.filename_tensor_name: save_path})

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 789, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
```

Answer (score -1):

Add the following lines when you import Tensorflow:

```
import tensorflow as tf  
tf.reset_default_graph()
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me, please could you give an explanation as to what this is supposed to do?